# Slide out and slid in Menu Sidebar html, css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code for sliding in and sliding out the menu that shows up in mobiles. the code works fine with new mobiles but in old mobiles does not slide in when I open the website the menu already out and cannot be slided in.

the code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#trigger").click(function() {
    $(".mainMenu").toggleClass("active");
  });

  $("#trigger").click(function() {
    $("#trigger").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1a001a;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #734088;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.mainMenu:before,
.mainMenu:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.mainMenu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mainMenu {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.Login:before,
.Login:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #330010;
  clear: both;
}
nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #A28FA9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #A28FA9;
}
.mainMenu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1a001a;
  height: auto;
}
.mainMenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
.mainMenu li li {
  list-style: none;
  display: list-item;
}
.mainMenu li li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #330010;
  clear: both;
}
.mainMenu li li a:hover {
  background-color: #A28FA9;
}
#trigger {
  display: none;
}
.firstList {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    background: #0d0d0d;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
  }
  nav li {
    height: 100%;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 16px 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  .mainMenu {
    clear: left;
  }
  .Login {
    clear: both;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
  nav ul li:hover {
    color: #bdc3c7;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-right: none;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    line-height: 35px;
  }
  nav.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
    transform: translate(0%, 0px);
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
  }
  #trigger {
    background-color: #1a001a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .firstList {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainMenu">
  <div class="">
    <div class="firstList">
      <ul class="mainMenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sublink 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sublink 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sublink 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the css `transform` property to hide your menu, and you haven't consequently prefixed it with vendor prefixes such as `-webkit-` or `-ms-`.

Try to determine which browser versions you want to support and prefix your css properties accordingly.

Here's an overview of which versions need those prefixes for the transform functionality: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 0):

Not all phones especially older phones support javascript, you should detect for javascript on page load and if no javascript is detected, make the slideout in css instead.

or use `<nonscript>place the css for slide out here</noscript>`

You can reference this site to see what phones are supported http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html